# Shell causing error in referencing variable in query

Tags: shell-script, quoting, google-cloud

I am executing a query in shell to access `Google Bigquery` table. Cannot figure out what is causing the error.

```
#!/bin/bash

file_path='/home/vikrant_singh_rana/test_bq_file.csv'

{
    read
    while IFS=, read -r name local_unit region_unit
    do
        test_tablename=XYZ_KLM_${name}
        echo $test_tablename
        bq query --format=pretty --use_legacy_sql=false --project_id='test-data-project' "select DATE(COLLECTTIME) DATE,count(distinct COLLECTTIME) as record_count FROM `${project_id}.Test_INGEST.${test_tablename}` where DATE(collecttime) >= '2020-12-01' group by DATE order by DATE asc;"
    done
} < $file_path
```

Below is input file to read:

```
vikrant_singh_rana@cloudshell:~$ cat test_bq_file.csv
name,local_unit,region_unit
AAAAA,hour,cell
BBBBB,15min,cell
```

error is:

```
read_bq_table.sh: line 22: .Test_INGEST.XYZ_KLM_AAAAA: command not found
Error in query string: Error processing job 'test-data-project:bqjob_r54dd3bbd143fcd42_0000017667292a54_1': Syntax error: Unexpected keyword WHERE at [1:81]
```

Comment: You might want to have a read through https://bobby-tables.com/ -- sanitize the data coming from that csv file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the double quoted string

```
"select DATE(COLLECTTIME) DATE,count(distinct COLLECTTIME) as record_count FROM `${project_id}.Test_INGEST.${test_tablename}` where DATE(collecttime) >= '2020-12-01' group by DATE order by DATE asc;"
```

the section

```
`${project_id}.Test_INGEST.${test_tablename}`
```

will be treated by the shell as a command substitution.  This happens because backticks introduce command substitutions when they occur unquoted or, as here, inside double quoted strings.  The shell will expand the variables inside the backticks and try to execute the result as a command, in a way similar to as if it had said

```
$(${project_id}.Test_INGEST.${test_tablename})
```

The output produced by executing the command within `` `...` `` or `$(...)` would then replace the command substitution, at least if it had been done on purpose with a command that made sense.  In your case, the backticks are part of the database syntax and must be passed as literal backticks without having the shell try to do its thing with them.

If you want the backticks to be literal, consider quoting them:

```
"select DATE(COLLECTTIME) DATE,count(distinct COLLECTTIME) as record_count FROM \`$project_id.Test_INGEST.$test_tablename\` where DATE(collecttime) >= '2020-12-01' group by DATE order by DATE asc;"
```

I've also removed unnecessary curly braces around variable names.

Ideally, you would also sanitize the values of the variables before injecting them into the database. You should, at the minimum, detect and reject strings containing backticks.

Also note that the code that you show does not appear to set a value for the `project_id` variable (which is why this part of the string, before `.Test_INGEST`, is empty in the error message).